# Если существует запись, то обновить ее, а если нет, то создать

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, mysqli

Составляю запрос вида: если существует запись, то обновить ее поле, а если нет, то создать. Код ниже:

```
$query_string = "IF EXISTS(SELECT user FROM tokens WHERE user = '$username') THEN UPDATE tokens SET token = '$token' WHERE user = '$username' ELSE INSERT INTO tokens(user, token, date, time, ip) VALUES ('$username', '$token', '$date', '$time', '$ip')";
```

Так вот, запрос не проходит, ошибка такая:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS(SELECT user FROM tokens WHERE user = 'testlogin') THEN UPDATE tokens S' at line 1

Я так понимаю, что там, где "UPDATE tokens S" ,возникла ошибка, и дальше вопрос выполняться не стал? В чем проблема, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ключи в таблице `tokens` какие? Если среди них есть `user`, то воспользуйтесь `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`.

Comment: А mysql поддерживает такой синтаксис - запрос IF EXISTS?

Comment: `insert... on duplicate key update...` не подойдет?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Синтаксис `if /**/ then` допустим только в хранимых процедурах.

Для вашей задачи, судя по всему, идеально подходит [`insert on duplicate key update`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO tokens(user, token, date, time, ip) 
  VALUES ('$username', '$token', '$date', '$time', '$ip') 
  on duplicate key update token = values(token)
```

Comment: Точно. Спасибо. И еще, если кто-то воспользуется этим решением - не забывайте в БД делать нужное поле уникальным :)

Answer (score 1):

Ну или попробовать разложить запрос на отдельные составляющие:

```
$query= mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT user FROM tokens");

if ($query){$result1 = mysql_query("UPDATE tokens SET token = '$token'");}

else {$result1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tokens(user, token, date, time, ip)
VALUES ( etc )");
```

Comment: что-то в таком роде :)